# Delaying Attacks With TimerTask Not Working Well

Tags: java, netbeans, keyboard-events, timertask, timedelay

I'm making a fighting game and I want the actions of the player to be timed so you can't spam the attack key and win easily.

Here is where I do the keyboard stuff and delay.  It does delay the first time, but then it the delay slowly decreases in time and ends up being 0 and lets you spam the key.  As you can see I've done many things to try and stop the key from registering in the delay etc.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (isAction == false) {
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = -1;
            if (nHeroX < -10) {
                dx = 0;
            }
            isRight = false;
            isMoving = true;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 1;
            if (nHeroX > 1200) {
                dx = 0;
            }
            isRight = true;
            isMoving = true;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_C) {
            dx = 0;
            isAction = true;
            isMoving = false;
            isBlock = true;
            nImage = 1;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_X) {
            dx = 0;
            isAction = true;
            isMoving = false;
            isWeak = true;
            nImage = 2;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_Z) {
            dx = 0;
            isAction = true;
            isMoving = false;
            isStrong = true;
            nImage = 3;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_P) {
            if (!pause) {
                pause = true;
            } else if (pause) {
                pause = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !isAction) {
        dx = 0;
        isMoving = false;
        nState = nImage = 1;
    } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_C && !isWeak && !isStrong) {
        delayTask = new DelayTask();
        tmrDelay.schedule(delayTask, 0, 500);
    } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_X && !isBlock && !isStrong) {
        z = new DelayTask();
        tmrDelay.schedule(z, 0, 450);
    } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_Z && !isBlock && !isWeak) {
        x = new DelayTask();
        tmrDelay.schedule(x, 0, 1200);
    }
    nImgNum = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    nDelay = 0;
}

//http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-se-api-tutorials/883-how-use-tmrDelay-java.html
class DelayTask extends TimerTask {

    public int nTimes = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        nTimes++;
        if (nTimes == 2) {
            isAction = isBlock = isStrong = isWeak = false;
            nState = nImage = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why my delay is messed up?  Thank you.

Also this code:

```
private class Keys extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        hero.keyPressed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        hero.keyReleased(e);
        if (hero.getPause()) {
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of `TimerTask`?

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Timer` with Swing applications as you risk running into Swing threading issues.

Comment: Rather than try to delay key presses, or use any type of Timer, why not instead work on the other side of the equation -- have the Player object ignore keyboard input if too close together. Give it a long field that is the time of the last keyboard input and if the delta is not big enough, simply ignore the input, return. Myself I'd use Key Bindings and not a KeyListener.

Comment: Hovercraft Full of Eels, is there a large benefit with using Key Bindings or is it just better internally?  The project I'm doing is due this Friday so I don't want to do anything "unimportant".

I will try doing the deltaTime stuff!

Comment: @Zoobasaurus: it is more flexible and by using it you avoid the nightmare of requiring a listened to component having to have the focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is just to remember the last time.

So:

```
 private long lastTime = 0;

 void doAction() {
     long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis()
     if (lastTime + MIN_DELAY < timeNow) {
        return;
     }
     lastTime = timeNow;

     // Do action
 }
```

All the stuff with timers etc is just approaching this from a much more complicated architecture than you need to.

Comment: I did something along the lines of what you did because your code didn't work in my program.  I initialized lastTime as System.currentTime() and did if (timeNow - lastTime < MIN_DELAY){ return.  That made it impossible to spam, all I have to do is make the image stay on the strong/weak etc for more than one cycle.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that's the same algorithm written slightly differently. Should work just fine :)

Comment: This works more like a hack! It does solve the problem but the timer delay keeps decreasing! it's 2020.. either I'm doing it wrong or they don't care!